# set_query_var doesn't seem to work on init hook

Tags: forms, query-variable, init

Based on the trick of using `set_query_var` with `get_template_part` to easily pass variables from one template file to another ([see here](http://help4cms.com/how-to-passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/): *Method 3*), I thought I could use the same method for passing complex information back to a page after a form submission (error messages, next steps, topic URLs, etc.)

Very simply, I have an `init` hook listening for the form submission set up like this:

```
function vnmProcessForm() {
    if (isset($_POST['form-value'])) {

        $formVal = sanitize_title($_POST['form-value']);

        if ($formVal == 'all-done') {
            set_query_var('form-message', 'It looks like you are all done with this step! Now move on to <a href="/dashboard">setting up your dashboard</a>.');
        } else {
            set_query_var('form-message', 'Please complete all options in the form.');
        }

        // It's a lot more complex than this, but... MVC.
    }
}

add_action('init', 'vnmProcessForm');
```

My form `action` is the same URL that the form resides on (so, essentially, a refresh); however, when I try `get_query_var('form-message')` on that page, I get nothing. If I spit out *all* `query_vars`, `form-message` isn't among them.

I'm sort of perplexed as to why this would work seamlessly for something like `get_template_part`, yet fails to work in this instance. Is it something to do with the `init` hook being too early?

In the meantime I have 'solved' this by simply using `$_POST` instead of `set_query_var`, but I'm genuinely curious to know why that isn't working.

Comment: Query parsing happens much later than init, I'll guess that you can't set query vars until after the query is parsed, or at least they have to be among [the list of known query vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) for them to survive parsing.

Comment: @Milo That was my guess, but I couldn't find anything definitive (as in, to say that `init` was indeed far too early). I guess I'll just stick with `$_POST` for now, as it's working for me.